# How can a department head recruit international students?

Tags: faculty-application, united-kingdom, europe, international-students, administration

I had a brief skype job interview for the position of department head at a mid-size/rank university in England. One of the key questions was about my plans for the international student recruitment. Contrary to other questions, I felt that they are not satisfied with my answer because I really didn't have a special plan for this. Still, I think a department head can support this but cannot think of any new plan to do so.

Do you have a convincing answer to this interview question?

Comment: Are you more interested in "how should I have answered this interview question" advice, or "how to effectively recruit international students as a department head" advice? The answers for two may be slightly different.

Comment: "Work full-time to reverse the Brexit decision."

Comment: An eventual answer also depends on your abilities: "I will lean on my international research contacts to establish joint degrees" is an idea... as long as you do have such contacts.

Comment: @JeffE Brixit is in favour of the international students. EU students are considered *home students*. I think the university in question is asking how to compensate the declining number of EU students by overseas students. In terms of tuition fee, Asian students are better than EU for the UK universities.